# Highcharts not displaying data labels for Pie chart in arabic

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts, I am facing a problem in Pie Charts for Arabic. Its working fine for English.
I tried rtl & ltr but its not working.

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },

```
title: {
    text: 'یک نمودار؟!',
    useHTML: true, //bug fixed `IE9` and `EDGE`
    style: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        fontFamily: 'tahoma',
        direction: 'rtl',
    },
},

tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        fontFamily: 'tahoma',
        direction: 'rtl',
    },
},

plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            y: -5, //Optional
            format: '\u202B' + '{point.name}', // \u202B is RLE char for RTL support
            style: {
                fontSize: '15px',
                fontFamily: 'tahoma',
                textShadow: false, //bug fixed IE9 and EDGE
            },
        },
    },
},

series: [{
    name: 'برند',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'الحجم الفعلي',
        y: 56.33
    }, {
        name: 'خرسانة جاهزة',
        y: 24.03,
    }, {
        name: 'خرسانة جاهزة',
        y: 10.38
    }, {
        name: 'سفاری؟!',
        y: 4.77
    }, {
        name: 'اوپرا؟!',
        y: 0.91
    }, {
        name: 'دیگر؟!',
        y: 0.2
    }],
}],
```

});

Example is here https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/h4kv0t9v/4/

Comment: its working in Firefox but not working in Chrome..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `plotOption` add `useHTML: true,`

[Forked Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3me9h7k2/)

```
    plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            y: -5, //Optional
            format: '\u202B' + '{point.name}', // \u202B is RLE char for RTL support
            style: {
                fontSize: '15px',
                fontFamily: 'tahoma',
                textShadow: false, //bug fixed IE9 and EDGE
            },
            useHTML: true,
        },
        //showInLegend: true,
    },
},
```