# The RTL language (Arabic) is not working with HighCharts pie chart correctly, how can I fix this?

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

Here is a very visualized result:

If the language is Arabic, the legend text became white and all the location is wrong. I'd like to know what can I do to fix it.

BTW, I have searched a while but gained no luck. I just found some `Highcharts.hasbidibug` property but even I set it, it's not working.

1 - The correct look in English

[image]

2 - The wrong look in Arabic

[image]

3 - The wrong look in Arabic with a red background

[image]

Comment: is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44082467/3898339)  similar to yours

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use (distance:??) inside  to controls where the text appears.it take negative or positive value

```
plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: ???,
```